# Google sheets script, range method not working

Tags: methods, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script to split a single column into multiple columns. I want it to work similar to excels text to columns. I'm Having trouble getting `range.splitTextToColumns()` to work, probably just using it wrong.

I just get "service error: spreadsheets". I don't know if this is a new unsupported method, as I don't see it in googles documentation for range yet.  Thank you.

here is my code:

```
function split1() {

  var results1 = ui.prompt(
  'Column to Split',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);  
  var results2 = ui.prompt(
  'Delimiter',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var column = results1.getResponseText();
  var test = results2.getResponseText();
  var delimiter ='"'+test+'"';
  var rng = column+'2:'+column;
  var range = sheet.getRange(rng);  
  var rangeH = range.getHeight();
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  range.splitTextToColumns(delimiter);
}
```

Comment: It seems Apps Script has gotten a bit more knowledgeable with its autocomplete suggestions lately. `splitTextToColumns` is not listed in the API Reference, but does appear in autocomplete. I was able to get to function as expected. **When do you get "Service Error: Spreadsheets"?** Saving? Running? Opening?

Comment: where did you define `sheet`? Also can you link the documentation for `splitTextToColumns` please? I can't find it anywhere and honestly didn't expect it to exist.

Comment: @Argyll there isn't any, at this time. It only shows up in the editor. It's a (set of) void method that operates on a range, and cause it to expand horizontally, to the right. If values exist in the expanded range, they are overwritten without prompting

Comment: Hi, I have active spreadsheet, and active sheet as golbal variables, that's why it's not in the code snippet sorry for not mentioning that. I get the error when running the script. Tried the suggested code below still not working for me.

Comment: Suggested code does work. It seems like this method prefers to work on a whole column, and works faster with no neighboring columns with values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function split1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var results1 = ui.prompt('Column to Split',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);  
  var results2 = ui.prompt('Delimiter',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var column = results1.getResponseText();
  var delimiter = results2.getResponseText();
  var range = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);
  range.splitTextToColumns(delimiter);
}
```